# data from one worksheet to another

Tags: excel, report, crm, names, states

I have 31,000 lines in an excel spreadsheet (A to N). Over the next 51 worksheets, I want to have the data for a particular state appear on that states sheet.  If I make a change on sheet 1, I want to effect the following 51.  Is this possible?  (from a CRM download)

Comment: ...or just autofilter the data sheet

Comment: The pivot table... I just don't understand them.  I'll have to look into the autofiler.  It's carrying any changes across the others that is really throwing me. Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can simply be done with Advanced Filter

Let's say all your data is on Sheet1.  Goto Sheet2 and in A1 put "State" and in A2 put "Alabama".  (Assuming your header title on sheet 1 is "State" and the value is "Alabama")

While still in sheet2(important), select Advanced Filter from the Data menu.
Select the Copy to another location option.
For the List Range, select all the data on sheet1.
For the Criteria Range, select A1:A2 on sheet2.
For the Copy to Range, select B1 on sheet 2.

That will pull all the data from sheet1 with a state of Alabama to sheet2.

That being said, I would definitely also look into Pivot Tables or Autofilter as previous commenters suggested.

Comment: Sounds so simple :)   I was going to use the christmas break to learn now to use pivot tables. Seems to be the answer for alot of my problems (at work...)  thanks both of you!